# Having an external application utilize Tridion TMS API?

Tags: 2013, web8, web8.5, sdl-tridion, translation-manager

I'm fairly new to Tridion and I had a question regarding using TMS within Tridion.  I came across this article [here](https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/sdl-tridion-workflow-translation-manager-integration) and am wondering if there was a way to utilize the Translation Manager API for applications that aren't Tridion objects tied to the Core API?  I have an application that needs to utilize TMS and am wondering if there is a way I can access the TMS API.